# mysql_insert_id возвращает 0 после UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код, который обновляет запись таблицы:

```
<?php
$date = date("d.m.Y G:i");
$servername = "localhost";
$database = "*";
$username = "*";
$password = "*";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
$sql ="UPDATE modifier SET articul='".$_POST['articul']."', name='".$_POST['name']."', description='".$_POST['description']."', price='".$_POST['price']."' WHERE id='".$_POST['id_moda']."'";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
mysqli_close($conn);
echo $id;
?>
```

Но `$id` почему то возвращает 0.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а почему должно быть что-то другое?

Comment: @Мелкий потому то `$id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);` - последняя созданная/обновленная строка.

Comment: Почему вы так решили? Это последний сиквенс сгенерированный AUTO_INCREMENT аттрибутом. Если новое значение не генерировалось - то откуда ему взяться?

Comment: чтобы при адпейте вернулось значение, нужно чтобы не произвольный столбец был изменен, а явно указан инкрементируемый, это значение и вернется.

Answer (score 3):

В мануале написана **чудовищно** мутная фраза. Для простоты можно принять, что нормальный запрос UPDATE, **разумеется**, не возвращает last_*insert*_id, поскольку никаких вставок не происходило.

Учитывая же, что при обновлении строки по id значение этого поля нам и так заведомо известно, то непонятно, зачем вообще может понадобится вызывать какие-либо функции, чтобы её получить.

Поэтому вместо $id = mysqli_insert_id($conn); пишем просто $id = $_POST['id_moda'];

А вот **реальная** проблема с этим запросом в том, что тут инъекция на инъекции сидит, и инъекцией погоняет.

Comment: http://joxi.ru/EA4oXo8HoDllB2